# Determining if vector space holds

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let A be a particular vector in $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$. Determine
whether the following is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$:

$S = \{B\in\Bbb R^{2\times2}| AB + B =0\}$

I have two ideas on how to approach this for scalar multiplication:

1. $AB = -B$
2. $(A+I)B = 0$

Though I have no clue how to apply scalar multiplication to show whether it's a subspace. But for addition perhaps:

$AB + B = 0, AC + C = 0$

$AB + B + AC + C = 0$

$A(B + C) + (B + C) = 0$

Since $B, C \in\Bbb R^{2\times2}$, the addition works out fine. I'm not sure if this is correct so can someone help me out with this problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ are the $2$ by $2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. Usually this is denoted $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. If this is the case, what you did to show $S$ is closed under addition is correct.

Comment: Yes it is, and thanks a lot for confirming. Still stuck on the multiplication though

Comment: Same idea, take $B \in S$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. What is $A( \lambda B)+ \lambda B=\lambda(AB+B)$? Remember, $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with usual addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check closure under addition, let $B,C \in S$ so $(A+I)B=(A+I)C=0$. Then $(A+I)(B+C)=(A+I)B+(A+I)C=0+0=0$ so $B+C \in S$. For scalar multiplication, let $B \in S$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(A+I)B=0$ so $(A+I)(\lambda B)=\lambda [(A+I)B]=\lambda \cdot 0=0$ so $\lambda B \in S$.

Answer (score 2):

For a subset of a vector space to be a subspace three things need to be satisfied.

1. The zero vector needs to be in the subset (in this case the zero matrix)
2. It needs to be closed under addition.
3. It needs to be closed under scalar multiplication.

It seems you did 2. fine. To show 1. $A\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0&0\\ 0&0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)+\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0&0\\ 0&0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0&0\\ 0&0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ so indeed $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0&0\\ 0&0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \in S$

To show 3. Suppose $k\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in S$. As $B\in S$ $AB+B=0$. Then $A(kB)+(kB)=k(AB+B)=k0=0$ so $kB\in S$. This shows S is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: You can replace $1)$ by making sure $S \neq \emptyset$. Then taking $A \in S$, closure under scalar multiplication means $-A \in S$. Closure under addition gives $0=A-A \in S$.

Comment: That is a bit circular as if you take $A\in S$ you already assume $S\neq \emptyset$

Comment: I was just showing how you can replace $1)$ since $S \neq \emptyset$ guarantees $0 \in S$. I guess what you're talking about is in this case, you would probably show $0 \in S$ anyway to show $S \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Of course $S\neq \emptyset$ implies $0\in S$.